# Angular 2 reactive forms custom validator apply only when form control is valid

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

How to implement a custom validator which is applied only when the form control is valid?

Something like this would be ideal:

```
static isValid(control: FormControl) {
    if (control.valid) {
        // custom validation checks here
        return {isNotValid: true};
    }
    return null;
}
```

but here `control.valid` is always true, so it will be applied even if other will invalidate the field.

Is there a way to achieve this?

## Detailed example

Source code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditional-validator

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyValidator } from './validators.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input [formControl]="form.get('name')">
    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form = new FormGroup ({
    name: new FormControl('', [
      MyValidator.isValidString,
      MyValidator.isValidName,
    ])
  });
}
```

`validators.service.ts`

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class MyValidator {
  static isValidString(control: FormControl) {
    if (!control.value || typeof control.value !== 'string') {
      return {isNotValidString: true};
    }
    return null;
  }

  static isValidName(control: FormControl) {
    if (control.valid && control.value !== 'John Doe') {
      return {isNotValidName: true};
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

How to make that `isValidName` validator is applied/executed only when control is valid, i.e. the previous validators returned `null`?
Cause right now, I believe angular will first run all sync validators, then will run all async validators, and only after will set the control status, which is the correct approach I think.

***Note***
This example is for demonstration only, it has no real live application.

Comment: why `control.valid` is always valid ? edit your question to add a minimum verifiable example.

Comment: @HDJEMAI I've updated the question and added a link to a live example. Hope this will clarify my dilemma.

Comment: Could you explain the use case here, why do you need it only applied when control is otherwise valid? Why wouldn't the code now as such be okay?

Comment: First, for the errors, I want to show only relevant error messages.
Second, to reduce useless calculations, this code is just a mock, in a real application validators are obviously more complex and could have some impact on performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this was to create a helper function:
`validators.service.ts`

```
import { AbstractControl, FormControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

export function runInOrder(validators: ValidatorFn[]): ValidatorFn {
  return (c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    for (const validator of validators) {
      const resp = validator(c);
      if (resp != null) {
        return resp;
      }
    }
    return null;
  };
}

export class MyValidator {
  // ...
}
```

and use it as a custom validator:
`app.component.ts`

```
import { MyValidator, runInOrder } from "./validators.service";

// ...
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl("", runInOrder([
      MyValidator.isValidString,
      MyValidator.isValidName
    ]))
  });
}
```

Full example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditional-validator-solution

Answer (score -1):

Try accessing parent property, assuming isValid validator is for the control which is first level child of your form control or else recursively find the parent to the top

```
static isValid(control: FormControl) {
    if(control.parent) {
       if(control.parent.valid) {
       //custom validation
       }
    }
 return null;
}
```